# Login across two meteor applications with the same database

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I have two Meteor applications that share the same database, so they have the same accounts. I want to make it so that when a user login on App1, he will be automatically logged in when he visit App2 as well.

Is this possible? How would you recommend me to do this? Thank you so much!

P.S. The Meteor official guide offers something like this at the "Shared Accounts" of the "Data Structure" section, but when I try it, it does not really work. Is it supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

> P.S. The Meteor official guide offers something like this at the "Shared Accounts" of the "Data Structure" section, but when I try it, it does not really work. Is it supposed to work?

This is the way to go, of course it works! There is a proof of concept of this architecture in [this example repository.](https://github.com/tmeasday/multi-app-accounts)

You won't be logged in automatically to the second app. You have to programmatically log in to the 2nd app when you log in in the first app.

The code in the guide is the way to go:

```
// This is server A's token as the default `Accounts` points at our server
const token = Accounts._storedLoginToken();

// We create a *second* accounts client pointing at server B
const app2 = DDP.connect('url://of.server.b');
const accounts2 = new AccountsClient({ connection: app2 });

// Now we can login with the token. Further calls to `accounts2` will be authenticated
accounts2.loginWithToken(token);
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried again with the same code provided in the example repository, and it did work, because the `console.log(accounts2.user());` did log the right user. However, as I try to go to app2, I am still logged out. Is this because the loginWithToken() is not resuming if there is a page refresh? How can I make the loginWithToken() persistent through a full page refresh/redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Two options (*can be used together*):

1. Point both apps to the same MongoDB, via `MONGO_URL` environment variable
2. Point clients from both websites to same WebSockets endpoint, via `DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL` environment variable

Example:
Main app:

```
ROOT_URL=https://example1.com
DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL=https://example1.com
MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo.example1.com:27000
```

Second app:

```
ROOT_URL=https://example2.com
DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL=https://example1.com
MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo.example1.com:27000
```